# Java - Is delegation the good solution in this case?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, overriding, delegation

Here is my question :

I have a huge class (HugeClass) and I wanted to split it into several little classes (LittleClass1, LittleClass2, ...). I heard about delegation. It sounds good, but I think it cannot works in my case.
Indeed, my little classes need some of the attributes of HugeClass:

```
public class  HugeClass
{
    // Attributes
    private Object object1;
    private Object object2;
    private Object object3;
    ...
    private Object objectN;

    // Delegation 1
    private LittleClass1  little1 = new LittleClass1 ();

    // Function delegated in the LittleClass1
    public void  delegated1 ()
    {
        little1.delegated1 ();
    }

}
```

Here an example of a Delegation class :

```
public class  LittleClass1
{
    public LittleClass1 ()
    {

    }

    public void  delegated1 ()
    {
        // Here, I need object1, object3, and more to work !
    }

}
```

The number of attributes needed by the delegated1 function can be large. So I think using the constructor of LittleClass1 is not very convenient.

And because LittleClass1 override only one method of HugeClass, I don't think that LittleClass1 should extends HugeClass.

Do you have an idea of a solution ? Using another pattern ?

Thanks !

**Update**

Delegated functions might need not only instance variables, but also instance functions :

```
public class  LittleClass2
{
    public LittleClass2 ()
    {

    }

    public void  delegated2 ()
    {
        // I need object2 and delegated1 to work !
    }

}
```

Giving HugeClass to the constructor might solve this problem. But is this a good solution ?

Comment: It would be nice to have more knowledge about `HugeClass` and its responsibilities.

Comment: You are very correct in stating "I don't think that LittleClass1 should extends HugeClass." Not only would this be mis-use of inheritance, but it also would not work. Regarding a solution, the devil is in the details. So please provide these.

Comment: HugeClass contains all the methods to interact with the API of a site web. In this cas, attributes are for example API variables, like a token, some header, some stubs, and some specifics to the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Breaking up a huge class into smaller classes is generally good to improve the maintainability, testability and overall quality of the code. The smaller chunks should be easier to reason about in isolation. What you want is to look for semantically distinct features of the huge class, and split them apart, first by extracting methods, and then by extracting classes. You're not necessarily looking for a pattern, as much as looking for refactoring techniques, like the ones in the books *Refactoring* and [*Working Effectively with Legacy Code*](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2010/08/working-effectively-with-legacy-code.html).

Now, if your little classes seem to share too many of the instance variables of the huge class, maybe you should take a step back and start with some low hanging fruits, like code that doesn't depend on too many variables; or try to find a grouping of those variables that semantically make sense to be encapsulated in a new object, what would decrease the number of these free variables and increase the quality of the design, as finding the latent *concepts* in the design make the code more *explicit* and *understandable*.

**UPDATE**: by the way, inheritance is really not a good idea. You want to decouple the concerns, and inheritance is just another more subtle way of coupling.

Comment: This is a  much better answer than the others so far. 1+ up-vote.

Comment: I would have liked to avoid creating new classes that will contain the instance variables, but I think this is the best solution. Thanks for that Jordão!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention something important: the function delegated1 may need the function delegated2 (in LittleClass2). Delegated functions need not only instance variables, but also instance functions. A solution might be to put HugeClass in parameter of the constructor of each LittleClass. But it doesn't seem lovely. Do you see another solution ?

Comment: @bill0ute: Again, try to rethink your refactoring approach. You'd like to decrease the dependencies between the classes. Maybe those 2 methods are cohesive enough that you keep them in the same little class; maybe you pass an instance of a little class to the other one. But passing the huge class around seems wrong, but could be a stepping stone to a better design.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need `LittleClass1` to subclass `HugeClass`, and its fields `protected`:

```
public abstract class HugeClass {
    // Attributes - now protected instead of private
    protected Object object1;
    protected Object object2;
    protected Object object3;
    ...
    protected Object objectN;

    -- Note: No delegation, no reference to LittleClass1 here    

    public abstract void delegated ()

}

public class LittleClass1 extends HugeClass {

    public void delegated () {
        // Here, you have access to object1, object2 etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that delegation doesn't work this way, that the protected fields from the parent would be completely different instances than the ones held by the current active HugeClass instance. Sorry, but your solution seems a mis-use of inheritance. Consider re-thinking this and then deleting this answer. -1 down-vote.

Comment: Actually, I tried this option. When you create an object HugeClass, it instanciates an object LittleClass1 for the delegation. LittleClass1 extends HugeClass, so you instanciates again the mother class which instanciates the delegation class LittleClass1 again, etc. I'm not sure I'm clear. But it doesn't works.

Comment: @bill0ute: nor am I surprised. You've selected the correct answer.

Comment: @bill0ute I think you guys have misunderstood me. I am saying **NOT** to delegate. Just subclass and use and instance of `LittleClass1` where you need that kind of functionality. I have added more code (the `abstract` stuff) to make this crystal clear. I think my answer is a good one btw.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think you guys have misunderstood me. I am saying **NOT** to delegate. Just subclass and use and instance of `LittleClass1` where you need that kind of functionality

Comment: @Bohemian: I understand, but I still feel that this answer is incorrect. But he is looking to refactor a god-class, and I don't see how inheritance will help in this situation. And again, the access to the protected fields in a child class object is a false access, since the objects referred to by these fields will be completely distinct from the ones held by any HugeClass instances.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have added more code (the `abstract` stuff) to make my answer crystal clear. Particularly, note that HugeClass is abstract. Your point of a god class may be relevant, but I think my answer is a good one given the question as stated - it sounds like this is what he really needs

Comment: I'll remove my down-vote, since now the parent class cannot be used to create an instance, but I think that @Jordão's is the better one since it addresses the refactoring issue, what I feel is the main concern of the question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just noticed an important "comment" on the accepted answer that *should* have been an edit to the question, that says the various delegates need access to each other. Given that, my answer won't work (of course), but technically the question didn't say this :)